# Regular Expressions How to exclude entering other URL's than domain URL

Tags: jquery, regex

Hello i wrote a regular expression to validate URL

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("url_validation", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^([ \t+])?(([http|https|HTTPS|HTTP]+:\/\/))?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/i.test(value);
}, "error")
```

I could not find a way to prevent entering anything after entering the domain : for example : - "http://www.mydomain.uk/whateverthing.ext"  i want to stop entering the "whateverthing after entering the domain . I could not figure out a way to solve this issue . can anyone give me a help?"(this will include validating the URL as well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so you want two things:

- validate the hostname;
- validate that the part after the /, if / there is, is empty.

You can proceed as such:

- validate your input against `^https?://([a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*)/?(.*)`;
- if the above does not match, you have an invalid URL;
- grab group 2: if non empty, it means a non empty path, invalid URL;
- grab group 1 and split it against `\.`.
- verify whether all groups are of length <= 255 *and* match `^[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$`: if one doesn't, invalid URL.

And that doesn't take IP addresses in the hostname part...

I am surprised anyhow that jQuery doesn't have methods to check for that. Have you looked?

Edit: it has: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url

Comment: well we allowed to enter example.com , www.example.com , http://www.example.com , http://example.com and also for https things . I want to resting what ever comes after .com or .com/

Comment: Yes, and this is exactly what my regex does!

Comment: Hold on. Do you also want to check the validity of the hostname as well? Your original question doesn't really say so...

Comment: My mistake we look for the URL as well

Comment: Hence my question above.  Do you also want to validate the hostname?

Comment: See edit. But you should really look into using an existing library.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6014/discussion-between-evlikosh-dawark-and-fge)